# Pivot Table with a condition

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, pivot, case

Consider I have a table like this

```
ID  DEPARTMENT
1   Production
1   IT
2   Sales
2   Marketing
2   Sales
```

How can I get a result like below

```
ID Production IT Sales Marketing
1  1          1  0     0
2  0          0  1     1
2  0          0  1     0
```

You will notice that in the original table for ID number 2 'Sales' department is repeated, so whenever a department is repeated there should be another entry in the pivoted table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is by adding a row_number before pivoting.
Then the pivot won't just group by ID.

```
SELECT ID, Production, IT, Sales, Marketing
FROM
(
  SELECT ID, DEPARTMENT
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, DEPARTMENT ORDER BY ID) AS RN
  FROM yourtable t
) Src
PIVOT 
(
   COUNT(*)
   FOR DEPARTMENT IN (
     'Production' AS Production,
     'IT' AS IT,
     'Sales' AS Sales, 
     'Marketing' AS Marketing
    ) 
) Pvt
```

| ID | PRODUCTION | IT | SALES | MARKETING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5e752f862a21297a12d472a52a3f21b2)*